# How do I remotely deploy a software package on Linux system?

Tags: deployment, remote-access, apt, automation, automated-install

I have a software package I wrote in Mono and I  want to be able to deploy it to Ubuntu server as part of my move to continuous integration and deployment work flow.

I was wondering if there is a tool to help me do that, some of the tasks I will need is

1. Register a new domain/hostname with linux
2. Install packaegs using apt-et
3. Copy files
4. Run some bash scripts

What are the solutions to streamline this process to automate, I understand that is more then one answer to this, I would love to hear all the methods pros and cons.

Thank you

Comment: Questions with multiple answers like this are typically marked "Community  Wiki" -- but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Did you do any research at all on this?  There's dozens of tools that you can use for this.

Answer (score 3):

There's at least chef, puppet, fabric, capistrano, cdist, bcfg2, cfengine and lots of other tools in this space.

You can also just cook something together yourself using ssh, public key authentication and some creative scripting.

Answer (score 0):

At my company we use [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/).

Comment: Does it deploy? I use Teamcity as a CI

Comment: I don't work directly with our BRI/CI team, but I believe they use scripts attached to Jenkins to install and uninstall our software during the CI cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Well, a very good but also "complex" solutions to beginners is Cfengine. An agent makes sure that each Cfengine-run some predefined Cfengine-scripts. Those scripts are able to configure your system, run shell commands and scripts, perform a number of various tasks and therefore is able to serve as an unattended configuration agent.

View more information here:
http://cfengine.com/